# Finishing only certain activities and sending data

Tags: java, android, android-activity, activity-finish

[image]

I want to finish only certain activities(3. and 4.) and sending data to 2. activity. How can I do that?

Comment: If you can not finish 3 before moving to 4 then Use `startActivityFoResult` to open Activity 3 and 4 and pass the data back to `Activity` so when you get data in `Activity` 3 you finish it and pass it back  to Activity 2 in same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 choices:

**1. Use `startActivityForResult()`**

In this case, `Activity2` should launch `Activity3` using `startActivityForResult()`. The result will be returned to `Activity2` in a call to `onActivityResult()`.

When `Activity3` launches `Activity4` it should use `startActivity()` and should set `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT` in the `Intent` and call `finish()`.

When `Activity4` is ready to return the data, it should call `setResult()` with the data and then `finish()`. This will return the result to `Activity2`.

**2. Use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`**

In this case, `Activity2` should launch `Activity3` using `startActivity()`.

`Activity3` should launch `Activity4` using `startActivity()`.

When `Activity4` is ready to return the data, it should create an `Intent` that contains the data (as "extras") and then do the following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
intent.addFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
               Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

This will cause `Activity3` and `Activity4` to be removed from the task stack `onNewIntent()` will be called on the existing instance of `Activity2`. `Activity2` should override `onNewIntent()` and can retrieve the returned data from the "extras" in the argument passed to `onNewIntent()`.

Comment: this solve sooooooo many problem of lazy programmer to read documentation

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing this.

1. set `noHistory="true"` for activity 3 in the manifest or intent flag while
   launching. In this case when you click back from
   4 app will directly go to 2 since 3 is not in the back stack.
2. Using android launch modes. you can put Activity 1,2 and 4 on one stack and
   activity 3 on a different stack.

Go through this page to understand the launch modes.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack